# Dreamweaver, how do you split the window 3 ways to show HTML, CSS, and Design view all at the same time?

Tags: dreamweaver

I just got a 27" Cinema Display and it seems like I could be using the workspace more efficiently in Dreamweaver. It would be great to be able to edit the HTML file and CSS file for a given page without switching windows, and also be able to see the effects on the site in real-time with Live View. I know there's a CSS panel, but I prefer to edit by hand in the code view. I've Googled around a bit but haven't found any solutions so far. I hope its possible...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Code Inspector may not help as it echoes the same code content of the code view. You could double+click another code file (could be a css, js or a php) in the File Window/panel. The file will be loaded in a separate code window. Now got to Window and choose Tile Horizontally or Vertically/

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do, I believe, is to open Window > Code Inspector and manually arrange it so you have three views next to each other. It's one of the shortcomings that really bug me as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Dreamweaver CC, you can easily achieve this in 3 steps:

1. Close tabs other than the ones you want to view
2. Go to **Window > Tile Vertically** (or horizontally, I just prefer vertically)
3. While your text cursor is in the file you want to show the design view for, click **Split** in the toolbar at the top of the window

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, I have a large 55" Sony Bravia with 4K resolution. Extremely productive with 6 windows open.

I found the solution from "Tan Gek Hua". Have code inspector turned on, then double click on the code files such as ".css" or ".js", Dreamweaver will magically shoot it out from it's own code window.